# Convert IEnumerable<List<string>> to IEnumerable<string> without third variable

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

Code :

```
XElement elem = XElement.Load("http://localhost:54002/sample.xml");

IEnumerable<List<String>> elem1 = (from member in elem.Elements("member")
                            where (String.Equals(member.Attribute("class").Value, "prem", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            select member.Elements("customer").Select(f => f.Value.ToString()).ToList());

 IEnumerable<string> out; // required output format
 foreach (List<string> temp in elem1)
        {
           out  = temp;
        }
```

Sample.XML

```
<root>
<member class="gold">
        <customer>cust3</customer>
        <customer>cust5</customer>
        <customer>cust8</customer>
        <customer>cust1</customer>
</member>
<member class="prem">
        <customer>cust5</customer>
        <customer>cust1</customer>
        <customer>cust3</customer>
        <customer>cust2</customer>
</member>
<member class="silver">
        <customer>cust5</customer>
        <customer>cust8</customer>
        <customer>cust1</customer>
        <customer>cust4</customer>
</member>
</root>
```

i need to return linq output in IEnumerable string format without using foreach loop. in simple words linq query itself should return the required ouput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany()` in LINQ fluent syntax to return `List<string>` directly :

```
IEnumerable<string> _out; // required output format
_out = elem.Elements("member")
           .Where(o => string.Equals(o.Attribute("class").Value, "prem", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
           .SelectMany(o => o.Elements("customer"))
           .Select(o => o.Value);
```

Or using `from` clause twice in query syntax to return the same, for example :

```
IEnumerable<string> _out; // required output format
_out = (from member in elem.Elements("member")
        where String.Equals(member.Attribute("class").Value, "prem", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        from customer in member.Elements("customer")
        select customer.Value);
```

**<kbd>[`Dotnetfiddle Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w1rWdJ)</kbd>**